# How to keep output window open in Eclipse's COBOL IDE?

Tags: eclipse, cobol

I need to know how to keep a window open so I can see the output of the screen when I run the program.  It flashes before I can see the program's output.  Thanks.

```
   program-id. Experiment as "Experiment".
   environment division.
   configuration section.
   Source-Computer. IBM-PC.
   Object-Computer. IBM-PC.
   special-names.
       console is crt.  

   data division.
   working-storage section.

   procedure division.
   Experiment-Start.
        Display "Hello World".
   end program Experiment.
```

Comment: I suggest you provide the version of Eclipse and any version information you have about the COBOL IDE.   (Is this IBM's RDZ?) You had suggested you were using Windows 8 (which I edited out of your original unmotivating title statement); what reason do you have believe that Windows 8 is relevant?

Comment: It is always nice to see the ID DIVISION/IDENTIFICATION DIVISION even if your program compiles without it, just to know none of the lines have gone missing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are describing normal behaviour.

If the Operating System has to open a window to run a program, then the Operating System will close that window when the program ends.

If *you* open the window, to get a DOS-prompt, and run the program, you will get different behaviour.

A little trick for testing is to put DISPLAY/ACCEPT statement immediate before the program ends:

In the WORKING-STORAGE SECTION

```
01  some-rubbish PIC X.
```

In the PROCEDURE DIVISION.

```
DISLAY "The Program is ending. Press Enter to allow it to finish."
ACCEPT some-rubbish FROM CONSOLE
```

There may well be something available in Eclipse, as it is a common development requirement, but until you find that, this should get you going.